# How can I split on more than one different char, while retaining the char, but also not on white space?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to split on 2 different chars but also **not** on space.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

my $line = "-abc=123 +def=456 -ghi 789";
my @arr = split(/([+-]\S+)/,$line);
foreach my $elem (@arr) {
    print "<${elem}>\n";  # '<' and '>' added to show where spaces are
}

exit;
```

This yields:

```
<>
<-abc=123>
< >
<+def=456>
< >
<-ghi>
< 789>
```

I want:

```
<-abc=123 >
<+def=456 >
<-ghi 789 >
```

(or preferably without those trailing spaces, but easy enough to trim).

It seems to want to split on space, even when that's not in the regex.
I suppose I could brute force this, walking the array and dropping the elements that are just a space, but I was hoping for something more elegant.

Answer (score 4):

You're not splitting on space, you're splitting on a `+` or `-` followed by some number of non-whitespace characters, and keeping the split strings. In this case, your regex matches `-abc=123`, `+def=456` and `-ghi`, which gives as the result of the split the empty space before `-abc=123`, the space between `-abc=123` and `+def=456`, the space between `+def=456` and `-ghi` and the text  `789` (after the `-ghi`). Since you have a capture group on your split string, you get those results in your output as well, giving as output from your code:

```
<>
<-abc=123>
< >
<+def=456>
< >
<-ghi>
< 789>
```

Instead, split where you are about to encounter a `+` or `-`:

```perl
my $line = "-abc=123 +def=456 -ghi 789";
my @arr = split(/(?=[+-])/,$line);
foreach my $elem (@arr) {
    print "<${elem}>\n";  # '<' and '>' added to show where spaces are
}
```

Output:

```
<-abc=123 >
<+def=456 >
<-ghi 789>
```

Note this doesn't give an empty first element despite splitting at the beginning of the string because the split condition has zero width (because it's a lookahead) and (from the [manual](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split)):

> a zero-width match at the beginning of EXPR never produces an empty field

Alternatively you could just match the strings you want i.e. a `+` or `-` followed by characters up to the next `+` or `-` or end-of-string:

```perl
my $line = "-abc=123 +def=456 -ghi 789";
my @arr = ($line =~ m/([+-][^+-]+)(?:\s|$)/g);
foreach my $elem (@arr) {
    print "<${elem}>\n";  # '<' and '>' added to show where spaces are
}
```

Output:

```
<-abc=123>
<+def=456>
<-ghi 789>
```

Answer (score 3):

A criterion for what *exactly* need be extracted and from what input isn't clear, with that space between the `ghi` and `789`, which must be captured together.  The desired output shows the input string split by spaces, well except for that last one.  But here are some options.

If you "must" [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split), one way would be to split on spaces that come after a number

```
my @t = split /(?<=[0-9])\s+/, $string;
```

In a command-line program, for ready testing (copy-paste at a terminal and run, in most shells)

```
perl -wE'$s = shift // q(-abc=123 +def=456 -ghi 789); 
    @p = split /(?<=[0-9])\s+/, $s; 
    say "|$_|" for @p'
```

This uses a [lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) to assert that there os a number before the space(s) we split on.  A lookbehind doesn't consume anything so that number isn't taken out.  (The parenthesis around it are a part of its syntax, not capturing.) Prints as desired.

However, I find it far more natural -- and far more flexible -- to capture wanted tokens by a straight regex here, rather than to specify the *other* parts (to split by), that we don't want.

One property of your string seems to be that spaces following a number separate tokens of interest (as used in the `split` example above). Then this could cut it

```
my @t = $string =~ /([^0-9]+[0-9]+)(?:\s|$)/g;
```

In a program

```
perl -wE'$s = shift // q(-abc=123 +def=456 -ghi 789); 
    @p = $s =~ /([^0-9]+[0-9]+)(?:\s|$)/g; 
    say "|$_|" for @p'
```

Or, parse the tokens of interest as they appear: non-space-non-numbers, then a `=` or a space, then numbers; capture each such sequence

```
my @t = $string =~ /([^0-9 ]+[=\s][0-9]+)/g;
```

Prints the same

```
perl -wE'$s = shift // q(-abc=123 +def=456 -ghi 789);                                      
    @p = $s =~ /([^0-9 ]+[=\s][0-9]+)/g; 
    say "|$_|" for @p'
```

---

I show command-line programs for perhaps readier testing; they can be copy-pasted into most shells as they stand.  By all means, transfer to a normal program, where the regex line remains unchanged.

In all examples one can submit a test stringx

```
perl -wE'...'  string
```

The one typed in, from the question, is merely a default for when no input is given

Answer (score 3):

`split` isn't the answer here because you can't easily tell what's a character to split and what's not (and you are getting extra characters in your output that you don't want). Instead of wrapping your head around the parts you want to ignore (separator retention mode will really screw with a maintenance programmer), choose the simpler problem of recognizing what you want to keep, which is one of:

- (SIGN) (NAME)   =   (VALUE)
- (SIGN) (NAME) SPACE (VALUE)

`NAME` can't have `=` or `SPACE`, so you really just need to figure out a match that can tell the difference between a `=` and `SPACE`, which is simple.

And, a match in list context returns its capture buffers, and we can make all captures with the `/g` flag. I spread out this pattern with insignificant whitespace with `/x` so it's a little easier to read:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

my $line = "-abc=123 +def=456 -ghi 789";

my @parts = $line =~ m/
    (
    [+-][^=\s]+  (?:=|\s+)  \S+
    )
    /xg;

foreach my $elem (@parts) {
    print "<${elem}>\n";
    }
```

The output is just what you want:

```
<-abc=123>
<+def=456>
<-ghi 789>
```

If you know more about what's allowed in `NAME` you can adjust `[^=\s]+` to be whatever that is.

If a `VALUE` can be empty, that's not so hard. Now the `VALUE` is optional, but also, the end of line anchor (`$`) picks up the case for a valueless `NAME` at the end. You just assume that a value can't start with `[+-]`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

my $line = "-abc=123 -lnm +def=456 -ghi 789 -xyx";

my @parts = $line =~ m/
    (
    [+-][^=\s]+  (?:=|\s+|$)  (?:[^+-]\S*)?
    )
    /xg;

foreach my $elem (@parts) {
    print "<${elem}>\n";
    }
```

This isn't perfect because it leaves a space after `-lnm`, but that's easy to fix later:

```
<-abc=123>
<-lnm >
<+def=456>
<-ghi 789>
<-xyx>
```

In days of old you would transform those values through `map`. This is how we typically trim strings in Perl:

```
my @parts = map { s/\A\s+|\s+\z//gr } $line =~ m/
    (
    [+-][^=\s]+  (?:=|\s+|$)  (?:[^+-]\S*)?
    )
    /xg;
```

However, v5.36 added a new builtin `trim` function:

```
use v5.36;
use experimental qw(builtin);
use builtin qw(trim);

...

my @parts = map { trim($_) } $line =~ m/
    (
    [+-][^=\s]+  (?:=|\s+|$)  (?:[^+-]\S*)?
    )
    /xg;
```